# Factorise multiple functions

Tags: javascript, refactoring

Dumb question maybe but:

How can I factorise this kind of code?

```
  var rsc = this.checkRsc(path)
  if (rsc)
```

Basically I want to check if a thing is null before any use of methods.

```
checkRsc: function(path) {
  var rsc = manager.get(path);
  if (rsc != undefined)
    return rsc;
  else
    return null;
},
func1: function(path) {
  var rsc = this.checkRsc(path)
  if (rsc)
    this.doStuff(rsc);
},
func2: function(path) {
  var rsc = this.checkRsc(path)
  if (rsc)
    this.doStuffAnotherStuff(rsc);
},
func3: function(path) {
  var wave = this.checkRsc(path)
  if (wave)
    this.andAgain(wave);
},
func4: function(path) {
  var rsc = this.checkRsc(path)
  if (rsc)
    this.AndsomethingElse(rsc);
}
```

Comment: `if(rsc != undefined)
        return rsc;
      else
        return null` ==> `return src || null;`

Comment: y well I didn't precise is the code in the func1,fun2,func3 etc.. that is repeated that i want to refactor ^^

Comment: Pass the method name to `func`, create `rsc`, check its existence, and call the method using bracket notation: `this[method_name](rsc);` when needed. This way you'll need only one function.

Comment: nice one too will check that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the function to be executed as well, like this

```
checkRsc: function(path, func, context) {
  var rsc = manager.get(path);
  if (rsc != undefined)
    return func.call(context, rsc);
  else
    return null;
},
```

and then invoke it like this

```
this.checkRsc(path, this.doStuff, this)
...
this.checkRsc(path, this.doStuffAnotherStuff, this)
...
this.checkRsc(path, this.andAgain, this)
```

---

**Note:** I recommended passing the context as well because, if you wanted to execute a function in a nested object, that would come in handy. For example,

```
this.checkRsc(path, this.nested.again, this.nested)
```

now,

```
    return func.call(context, rsc);
```

will be working like this

```
    return [this.nested.again func obj (without context)].call(this.nested, rsc);
```